# Error message when trying to import db.sql into my database on phpMyAdmin?

Tags: sql, database, file-upload, import, phpmyadmin

I'm using phpMyAdmin to hold my databases.

I made a database and I pressed the "import" button.
After that, I chose my file `db.sql`

And then I clicked the go button.
Instead of importing my file, this error message comes up:

Error
SQL query:

```
TABLE structure FOR TABLE `category` -- 
CREATE TABLE `category` (

`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`category` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY ( `id` )
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT =9;
```

MySQL said:

### #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Table structure for table `category`

CREATE TABLE `category` (
`id` int(1' at line 1

What does all of this mean?

And how do I get my file to import to the database?

How do I fix this?

I'm trying to open up an ebook that I need to read, and I can't find it anywhere else.

Thanks, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It seems to be ther is an syntax  error in the query before 
`TABLE structure FOR TABLE category` line.. check the the above line of this line...

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect the first line to be a comment (start with `--`). The lack of the comment delimiter combined with what isn't really an SQL statement are causing your error message since MySQL doesn't know what to do with the line `` TABLE structure FOR TABLE `category` ``.

Where did this SQL statement come from? Either there's a bad copy/paste or the original source is missing the comment part.

Either remove the first line or add the two dashes to make MySQL ignore it as a comment:
`` -- TABLE structure FOR TABLE `category` -- ``

Also, the trailing `--` is pretty much ignored and probably the result also of a bad copy/paste.